# Should values ever be stored on the instance of a component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Can I ever do something like this? Does it avoid issues with asynchronous state changes?

```
class Widget extends React.Component {

  constructor () {
    this.value = '123';
  }

  render () {
    var hello = this.value;
    // ...
  }
}
```

Comment: If you want to change the state, you should use `setState()`.

Comment: @zynkn The example isn't using state at all.

Comment: Why was this question down voted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can use Class properties to store data, and you can use that in render method. For eg: constants

But you will have to use state to store data that directly affects how a component is rendered, and use setState function to update state as this triggers component re-render. Setting data in simple class property wont re-render component.

`Does it avoid issues with asynchronous state changes?`
No. after your asynchronous operation, for eg: an ajax api fetch, if you are simply setting `this.data = fetchedData` ReactDom wont know that new data has arrived and it should re render the component. But if you are using setState there it will know and it can trigger all the needed lifecycle methods and render method.

Comment: Is the point of "state" that it automatically triggers a render when it's changed?

Comment: Yes as far as I understand state should be used to store data that is internal to the component and directly affect how component is rendered. Whereas props is something passed from outside the component, for eg: a checkbox outside the component is clicked and your component has to react to that by re rendering.

Comment: I'm referring to the asynchronous update of the state object. For example, if I set a state item in a function and then refer to it in the same function, it can still have the old value.

Answer (score 0):

> Can I ever do something like this?

Yes sure.

> Does it avoid issues with asynchronous state changes?

No, indeed it makes things worse. For state changes, use `setState` !

Comment: It's not a "state" change.

Answer (score 0):

```js
class Widget extends React.Component {

  constructor () {
    this.state = {
      value: '123'
    }
  }
  render () {
    var hello = this.state.value;
    // ...
  }
}
```

Comment: `thist`. And why should that be better?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that.
But whenever the value will be changed like

this.value = "newValue"

the changes will not be reflected in the VIEW as render() will not be called by this.

You can just set the state for viewing this change instantly by setting a random id change in state like

```
this.value = "newValue"; 
this.setState({id:Math.random()});
```